# how to show/hide keyboard automatically like the UINavigationController or UItabBarcontroller?

Tags: ios

when a UIViewcontroller was in a container like UINavigationController or UITabBarController,if you have a UITextfiled in its view hierarchy which is the firstResponder,the keyboard will hide when then controller's view disappear and show when the view appear automatically,how can I do this in my custom container?

Comment: You can use this properties [textfield becomeFirstResponder]; and     [textfield resignFirstResponder];

Comment: that means i need to traversal the view hierarchy to find the textfiled and store it.

Comment: Yes dude you are right asper my knowledge